# Export INSERT command from oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have imported data into oracle using excel from IMPORT DATA option in tables. I need to now export the create and insert statements into text file. I can find the create statement commands but not INSERT. Any idea where I can find the INSERT statements?

Comment: Have you tried Google???

Answer (score 3):

You can download [SQLcl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/downloads/index.html) or SQL Developer. Simply set the sqlformat to insert and you'll have insert statements.

```
sql klrice/klrice
SQLcl: Release 18.1 Production on Fri Feb 09 12:10:04 2018

SQL> set sqlformat insert
SQL> select * from emp;
REM INSERTING into EMP
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',null,to_timestamp('17-NOV-81','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),5000,null,10);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,to_timestamp('01-MAY-81','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),2850,null,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,to_timestamp('09-JUN-81','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),2450,null,10);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,to_timestamp('02-APR-81','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),2975,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,to_timestamp('19-APR-87','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),3000,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,to_timestamp('03-DEC-81','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),3000,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,to_timestamp('17-DEC-80','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),800,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,to_timestamp('20-FEB-81','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),1600,300,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,to_timestamp('22-FEB-81','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),1250,500,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,to_timestamp('28-SEP-81','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),1250,1400,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,to_timestamp('08-SEP-81','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),1500,0,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,to_timestamp('23-MAY-87','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),1100,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,to_timestamp('03-DEC-81','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),950,null,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,to_timestamp('23-JAN-82','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),1300,null,10);

14 rows selected. 

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea where I can find the INSERT statements?

Right-click table name in SQL Developer; select "**Export ...**" from the menu that opens and follow instructions.

Note that - as long as `INSERT INTO` statements are an acceptable *solution* if table is small (i.e. doesn't contain many rows), it becomes a nightmare for large tables because it is simply too slow.

I'd suggest you to read about two alternative options:

- [Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_overview.htm#g1015896) (both Export and Import) or, at least, the *original* EXP and IMP utilities
- [SQL Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm#g1013706)

Both will be MUCH faster than `INSERT INTO` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this in two parts, you can get the inserts AS you do the Excel import.

In the wizard, choose the script option. This will give you the INSERTS.

[image]

You can also use sqldevs cart and DB export options to grab your table. It will let you grab the ddl and inserts or just one or the other.